# GAE for Java Best Practice. How to store sorted List<string> in a most optimal way

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the best way to store lists (collections) of simple types in Google App Engine for Java?

I usually use something like that:

```
public class Person {
// ....     

@Persistent(serialized = "true")
 private List<Date> DatesList;

// ....
}
```

I am not sure how it is stored in DataStore, atomically or as a list of references? Hence wanted to get your advice on implementing these kinds of collections in a best way for performance of a query.

Like in the example above, when I load the object, will the DateList will be loaded with it. Or it will be loaded when accessed fro first time?

Does **@defaultFetchGroup** attribute affect this collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list will be returned/loaded by the datastore along with the rest of the object, not when it is first referenced.

[**GAE JDO Collections**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Collections)
If a field is declared as a List, objects returned by the datastore have an ArrayList value. If a field is declared as a Set, the datastore returns a HashSet. If a field is declared as a SortedSet, the datastore returns a TreeSet.

Comment: this is right, but the "loading referenced entities" link is misleading, and should probably be removed. the question is just talking about a simple list property, not reference properties that point to separate entities.